# TVirtualStringTree: OnEnter and OnFocusChange

Tags: delphi, tvirtualstringtree

I have an interface like file explorer with 2 VirtualStringTree, first for folders and second for files from these folders. On the right panel, I need to show information about the selected file or folder. This is a screenshot for example:

[image: VirtualStringTree panels]

Ok, this is my code to process currently selected file or folder:

```
procedure OnFoldersFocusChange();
begin
  // Show the selected Folder info on panel
end;

procedure OnFilesFocusChange();
begin
  // Show the selected File info on panel
end;
```

This is works, but when we have selected folder and selected file on both VitrualStringTree's, that when we switch between this file and folder nothing happens, `OnFocusChange` does not execute and I will not know what is focused now: folder or file.

The second iteration is processing `OnEnter` events:

```
procedure OnFoldersEnter();
begin
  OnFoldersFocusChange();
end;

procedure OnFilesEnter();
begin
  OnFilesFocusChange();
end;
```

Ok, now all works fine, but when we have focused Files control and I click on the Folders control, but not on the focused folder than I have 2 executions of the `OnFolderFocusChange`. The first will be executed in `OnFolderEnter` for the previously focused folder and second execution for new focused folder.

What I should change to avoid execution for previously focused folder?